# Is there a good package for translation of two languages in humanities?

Tags: enumerate, minipage, multicolumn

I am translating a classics text from German to Korean and I have to divide one page to two sections: source - target. Each of the paragraphs needs enumeration and they have to be vertically aligned.
If one of the source or the target is too short, then the bottom of the short paragraph should be filled with blank space.

I used this code to try and achieve this:

```latex
\newcommand\litem[1]{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}\qquad}
\newcommand\ritem[1]{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}}

\begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}]
        \item \litem{
        Im Fürsichsein ist das qualitative Sein vollendet; es ist das unendliche Sein.
        }\ritem{
        대자존재 안에서 질적 존재는 완성된다. 그것은 무한한 존재이다.
        }
\end{enumerate}
```

but I think it's too arbitrary, not robust and not systematized. Above all, using `minipage` creates some trouble in multiple pages. Paragraph breaking in `minipage` does not work in some cases too. For example, if a `minipage` is too long vertically, then it can't be broken into two pieces or it takes up a lot space for page breaking.

Are there some great packages for humanities better than my code?

[image]

Comment: There are quite a few packages for that; my first suggestions would be [reledpar](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/reledpar) or [paracol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol), but you have numbered paragraphs, which might complicate things a bit.

Comment: Off topic:  I find it hard to believe that the hyphenation "Bes-timmten" is correct.  I would expect "Be-stimmten".  Are you using babel?

Comment: No I didn't. because, there's a compilation error when I imported babel. in the example image, some of the hyphenation and translation can have errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using paracol. Disclaimer: I do not speak Korean; this is just text I copied from the Google font page for Noto Serif Korean. You will need this font to compile the example (with lualatex), but it can be changed with `\setmainhangulfont` etc. Also, the left side is not in German (well, it was before translation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol,kantlipsum,enumitem,luatexko}
\usepackage{microtype} % try different settings or completely without

\newcommand{\mynewpara}{\switchcolumn*\item}
\newcommand{\myswitch}{\switchcolumn\item[]}
\newenvironment{numberedparas}{%
    \begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}]%
    \begin{paracol}{2}%
    \sloppy%
    \item%
    }%
    {%
    \end{paracol}%
    \end{enumerate}%
    }%
    
\newcommand{\somekoreantext}{이 선언의 어떠한 규정도 어떤 국가, 집단 또는 개인에게 이 
선언에 규정된 어떠한 권리와 자유를 파괴하기 위한 활동에 가담하거나 또는 행위를 할 수 있는 
권리가 있는 것으로 해석되어서는 아니된다. 모든 인류 구성원의 천부의 존엄성과 동등하고 양도
할 수 없는 권리를 인정하는 것이 세계의 자 유, 정의 및 평화의 기초이며}

\begin{document}

\begin{numberedparas}
\kant[1][1-2]
\myswitch
\somekoreantext
\mynewpara
\kant[1][2]
\myswitch
\somekoreantext
\mynewpara
\kant[3][1-4]
\myswitch
\somekoreantext
\end{numberedparas}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The use of `microtype` and `\sloppy` is thanks to suggestions in the comments in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/661532/208544) I asked. Without `\sloppy` the text tends to form overfull lines that run into the margin. The interword spacing may also be improved with wider columns (see [paracol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol) documentation for how to do this).