# text justification with paracol and enumitem

Tags: enumerate, paracol, justification

While thinking about an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/661523/208544) involving a side-by-side translated text with numbered paragraphs, my initial (naive) solution works fine, except for the fact that the column text is not properly justified. At several points the text protrudes into the margin. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,paracol,enumitem}
\newcommand{\mynewpara}{\switchcolumn*\item}
\newcommand{\myswitch}{\switchcolumn\item[]}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}]
\begin{paracol}{2}
\item \lipsum[1][1-5]
\myswitch
\lipsum[2]
\mynewpara
\lipsum[8]
\myswitch
\lipsum[4][1-5]
\end{paracol}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is not a case of `\switchcolumn` inside a list environment *inside* a paracol environment, which is warned against [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484758/208544) and in the [paracol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol) documentation.

Considering that in either an enumerate or paracol environment by itself, the text is correctly justified, why does this particular combination cause the text to protrude?

### Addendum

In similarly sized columns using `enumerate` and `multicols`, the result appears much better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,enumitem,multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that here the "columns" environment is outside the "list" environment (this is not recommended with paracol).

Comment: Off-topic: If you load the `microtype` package and insert a `\sloppy` directive immediately after the first `\myswitch` directive, the overfull lines vanish -- at least for the four text snippets you have chosen to typeset.

Comment: If you load both `microtype` and `ragged2e` and insert `\RaggedRight` in `paracol` as the first thing, would that improve the text? In case it does and you plan to have more `paracol` instances, you could add a hook in preamble, instead, to avoid repetition: `\AddToHook{env/paracol/before}{\RaggedRight}`.

Comment: I have always had problems with lipsum in narrow columns WRT hyphenation.  I use \sloppy,  but \raggedright would also work.

Comment: @Celdor I think `\sloppy` is more what I'm after, so I can do `\AddToHook{env/paracol/before}{\sloppy}`. But shouldn't I use `env/paracol/begin` instead so that it only affects the scope of the environment?

Comment: It is not really a paracol problem, but a narrow column problem.  multicol, minipage, \parbox, flowfram etc. will all have this problem.

Comment: @JohnKormylo see edit. Without any `\sloppy` declarations the result is much better in multicols of similar size. Perhaps multicols does this automatically.

Comment: Also consider: Hyphenation patterns for "Latin" (none being applied in this case, since it looks like English rules are being applied: `con-` breaks, `lectus` doesn't, etc).

Comment: @mbert - I know that some things (\marginpar?) do switch to \sloppy automatically.  You could test this by adding \fussy and see if it changes.

Comment: @mbert `\RaggedRight` was an alternative to `\sloppy` as it was designed to work in significantly narrow columns similarly to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those in the comments, and after reading the [`multicol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) documentation, the way to fix this while having justified columns is to change the value of `\tolerance`. The `\sloppy` command sets `\tolerance` to 10000 (to TeX, the same as infinity) so `multicols` sets it to 9999 which allows bad spacing but not the absolute worst, though in my simple tests I couldn't make an example where this differed from `\sloppy`. Also, since Latin hyphenation patterns are not in effect when you use `lipsum` in an English document, you can use `kantlipsum` for a better picture of how your columns will look.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,kantlipsum,paracol,enumitem}
\newcommand{\mynewpara}{\switchcolumn*\item}
\newcommand{\myswitch}{\switchcolumn\item[]}

\newenvironment{numberedparas}{%
    \begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}]%
    \begin{paracol}{2}%
    \tolerance=9999%
    \item%
    }%
    {%
    \end{paracol}%
    \end{enumerate}%
    }%


\begin{document}

\begin{numberedparas}
\kant[1][1-5]
\myswitch
\kant[2]
\mynewpara
\kant[8]
\myswitch
\kant[4][1-5]
\end{numberedparas}

\newpage

\begin{numberedparas}
\lipsum[1][1-5]
\myswitch
\lipsum[2]
\mynewpara
\lipsum[8]
\myswitch
\lipsum[4][1-5]
\end{numberedparas}

\end{document}
```

[image: cols]